# Cannot telnet via AWS EC2 to SMTP(MTA) server on port 25

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ec2, smtp

I'm trying to test an email validation service on AWS EC2 instance, where my program would query the SMTP server (Mail Transfer Agent on port 25). For testing purposes, I replicated the program using Telnet connection, which works fine on my local machine:

```
telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Trying 66.102.1.27...
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP a20si12977453wrg.559 - gsmtp
HELO gmail.com
250 mx.google.com at your service
MAIL FROM:<testing@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK a20si12977453wrg.559 - gsmtp
RCPT TO:<thisemailwillneverexist@gmail.com>
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser a20si12977453wrg.559 - gsmtp
```

Telnet, however, doesn't work on EC2, as in the example below:

```
telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Trying 74.125.133.26...
telnet: connect to address 74.125.133.26: Connection timed out
Trying 2a00:1450:400c:c08::1a...
telnet: connect to address 2a00:1450:400c:c08::1a: Network is unreachable
```

EC2 is running a linux instance and allows all outbound connection. My guess here is that AWS doesn't let you connect to SMTP server on port 25 to prevent spam, but I haven't seen the confirmation of that. Any suggestions how I could fix this? If AWS is too rigid, any alternative AWS-like services where I could migrate my project?

Thank you!

Comment: Can it connect to your machine (or a server you have control of) on another port (any random chosen by you or perhaps 587, smtp submission port)?

Comment: Yes, it can connect on other ports to other servers. It can also for example connect to smtp.gmail.com via port 587 or 465 but that's Mail Submission Agent. It's odd.

Comment: *Any suggestions how I could fix this?* - use a mail sending service? Run a port forward on a machine you control? Run your own mail server on an alternative port?

Answer (score 5):

AWS blocks outbound traffic on port 25 by default for EC2 instances and Lambda functions (source: [AWS support page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/)).

You can place a request for removing restriction on port 25 for your EC2 instance following this link: https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request. You have to be logged in your AWS account to be able to access this link.

Comment: That's a shame. My request was denied as they didn't like the use case, even though no emails would have been sent. Are there any alternatives to AWS that are a bit more liberal in their approach regarding outbound port 25?